# NUnit Runners have some errors. MSBuild

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

```
C:\CCNet\*\WorkingDirectory\build\*_NUnit.targets (17,5):

errorMSB3073: The command ""C:\CCNet\*\WorkingDirectory\build\..\src\packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.2\tools\nunit-console.exe" *.Tests.dll /xml:nunit-results.xml /noshadow /framework=v4.0.30319" exited with code -100.
```

What could be it?
On the local machine tests are run and long run (and not all) or take off.
And server machine test cannot be runned.

Answer (score 0):

The error `MSB3073` often indicates some kind of permission issue.  Does whatever account\user running the build have access to where the file `nunit-results.xml` is supposed to be copied to?

Also, is it a long path?  There is normally a 256 character limit (remember that the path might be shorter on your machine).

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this by passing the excluded categories incorrectly.

```
...nunit-console.exe ... /exclude:Integration Tests,Integration ...
```

should include inverted commas when a space is present:

```
...nunit-console.exe ... /exclude:"Integration Tests",Integration ...
```